# SQL Schema Compare from one SQL version to another not working

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

In Visual Studio (2013 or 2015, they both do the same) > SQL Schema Compare, I am trying to copy the schema from one database on sql 2008, to databases on sql 2014. From 2008 -> 2008 works fine, 2014->2014 works fine, but when trying to go from 2008->2014, it does not work. After running the compare and hitting update it just sits on "Schema Compare generate script (db1 > db2) until it eventually freezes and visual studio just says it is busy, and never finishes. I can not find a log that explains what point it gets stuck on either.

Under options I have tried to ignore compatibility issues but this does not fix it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be a schema compare bug. I'd suggest first ensuring that you're using the latest version of the SQL Server tools (available for download here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)

Then, if the problem still persists, I'd suggest capturing a trace log using the below instructions and opening a Connect issue that describes the problem and includes the trace log at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx using the category "Developer Tools (SSDT, BIDS, etc.)"

Gathering an Event Log for SSDT

- Open a new command prompt as Administrator.
- Run this command logman create trace -n DacFxDebug -p "Microsoft-SQLServerDataTools" 0x800 -o "%LOCALAPPDATA%\DacFxDebug.etl" -ets
- Then run this command: logman create trace -n SSDTDebug -p "Microsoft-SQLServerDataToolsVS" 0x800 -o "%LOCALAPPDATA%\SSDTDebug.etl" -ets
- Run SSDT and reproduce the issue.
- Go back to the command prompt and run the following commands:
  logman stop DacFxDebug -ets
  logman stop SSDTDebug -ets
- The resulting ETL files will be located at %LOCALAPPDATA%\SSDTDebug.etl & %LOCALAPPDATA%\DacFxDebug.etl.

Comment: For the first command, after breaking it into two command the second one reports -ets is unknown, but it works for the first command. Running without the -ets runs fine.

Comment: Just figured out, the - you're copy pasting on the second command is a program that altered a -- into one and isn't valid, but i'm running it now.

Comment: I've edited the text above, which was copy/pasted from elsewhere and didn't work well with StackOverflow's formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hitting "Update" try "Generate Script", and then run the script on the destination database.

Comment: Both do the same thing, it doesn't even get to that point. Usually, two lines appear below it in the window that appears for that line, but neither of them appear, it doesn't get to the preview let alone generating the script.